# Pandas MultiIndex Aggregation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to do some aggregation on a multi-index`DataFrame` based on a `DatetimeIndex` generated from [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html).

My `DatetimeIndex` looks like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-05-30', '2000-05-31', '2000-06-01' ... '2001-1-31'])
```

And my multi-index `DateFrame` looks like this:

```
                     value
date          id    
2000-05-31    1        0
              2        1                   
              3        1
2000-06-30    2        1
              3        0
              4        0
2000-07-30    2        1
              4        0
              1        0
2002-09-30    1        1
              3        1
```

**The dates in the `DatetimeIndex` may or may not be in the date index**.

I need to retrieve all the `id` such that the percentage of `value==1` is greater than or equal to some decimal threshold e.g. `0.6` for all the rows where the date for that `id` is in the `DatetimeIndex`.

For example if the threshold is `0.5`, then the output should be `[2, 3]` or some `DataFrame` containing `2` and `3`.

`1` does not meet the requirement because `2002-09-30` is not in the `DatetimeIndex`.

I have a solution with loops and dictonaries to keep track of how often `value==1` for each id, but it runs very slowly.

**How can I utilize `pandas` to perform this aggregation?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#define range
rng = pd.date_range('2000-05-30', '2000-7-01')

#filtering with isin
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('date').isin(rng)]

#get all treshes
s = df.groupby('id')['value'].mean()
print (s)
id
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    0.5
4    0.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

#get all values of index by tresh
a = s.index[s >= 0.5].tolist()
print (a)
[2, 3]
```

Comment: I think my question was a little unclear, but I am trying to get the ids with a mean > .6 for all the dates in the date_range

Comment: Yes, you are right. Some things was unclear for me. What is desired output  with your sample data , `rng = pd.date_range('2000-05-30', '2000-7-01')` and range `0.5` ?

Comment: id 1 has a mean of 0 for dates in the date_range, mean(id 2) = 1, mean(id 3) = .5 and mean(id 4) = 0 so if the threshold is 0.5, the output should be `2, 3`

Comment: Sorry, I overcomplicated solution. Check completely changed answer.